# Angular material: after migration to 15 version, rgba background in table works different

Tags: angular-material, angular-material2

I've migrated to Angular Material 15 and found out, that background in my tables  has different color. I've come to Material site, went to table component and changed background color for row there. Also, made this for another version of material. Here are the results:

[Version 14:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnVYa.png)

[Version 15:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTrhV.png)

As you can see, background has same color value, but looks like another color. I thought, that in 14 version they had some opacity set on the table, but didn't found that. And the trouble reproduces only when setting rgba. rgb or hex works fine.

Comment: Angular 15 switches to MDC components with some changes of DOM and styles. This is definitely a weird problem. I have no solution yet, but would recommend to play around with the `background` related CSS rules on the `table` and `tbody` element.